# How can I configure Sentry using Kafka on prem?

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, sentry

I performed the sentry installation following the self hosted guide here https://develop.sentry.dev/self-hosted/ and it works right.
Now I would like to custom the installation using Kafka on prem.
What kind of changes should I have to do in the install.sh / docker-compose.yml / other files?

Comment: Haven't used it, but I don't see Kafka mentioned as an integration https://develop.sentry.dev/integrations/  But Kafka can easily be added to a Docker Compose file... Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: In the self-hosted guide you can use the install.sh script that provide all the sentry components installed using docker containers. I want to edit the Kafka section in the docker compose and use a Kafka installed on prem on the server itself or on an other server

Comment: Okay. Then use the bootstrap server of your actual Kafka address... What errors do you get when you try that? Can you share your config files what you tried?